# Bash file shows "ln: command not found"

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script to setup my development environment.  The script is running as root but I get the error `line 11: ln: command not found`

```
#!/bin/bash
#Require script to run as root - doesn't work - syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
#if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0]]; then
#       echo "Script must be run as root";
#       exit;
#fi

#PHPMyAdmin
PATH="/etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.local";
if [ ! -a PATH ]; then
        ln -s /home/user/Ubuntu\ One/htdocs/vhosts/phpmyadmin.local PATH;
        a2ensite phpmyadmin.local;
fi
```

Comment: Other problems: `[ ! -a PATH ]` should be `[ ! -a $PATH ]` -- or, better yet, `[ ! -a "$PATH" ]`. (Or whatever you decide to rename it to.) You don't need a semicolon at the end of each line. And in the commented-out section at the top, add a space between the `0` and the `]]`; as it is, `0]]` is parsed as a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` tells the shell where to look for commands. In your case, it looks for `ln` somewhere in `/etc` and predictably doesn't find it there.

You should use a different name.

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to use lowercase (or mixed case) variable names in shell scripts -- there are a number of all-caps variable names with special meanings, and it's easy to clobber one you're not aware of.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> PATH=...
> ```

Congratulations, you've clobbered [how the shell finds commands](https://rlworkman.net/howtos/rute/node7.html#SECTION007180000000000000000). Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks... this was my first bash script, so I had no idea ^_^

Comment: To be picky: `PATH` not only alter how the shell finds command, but how `execvp` find commands -and [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) is used by a lot of software, outside of the shell, to run other programs.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : the link is broken now